# CodeIgniter - update single record by ID - failing

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

Am a new user to `CodeIgniter`, have looked at other posts and the answers given sadly don't solve this issue.

Am using a form to create records (also uploads image file and creates link to image as field in db) This all works. I am now trying to edit a particular record. I have a view with the form and this works and is pre-filled from the db using `$id = $this->uri->segment(3)` to grab the correct record - this all works.

Where it fails is then in updating the record.

My controller...

```
    function edit_stock_vehicle_record()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');


        // field name, error message, validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('make', 'Make', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('model', 'Model', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('fuel', 'Fuel Type', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('enginesize', 'Engine Size', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('trans', 'Transmission', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('reg_no', 'Registration Number', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('year', 'Year', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('colour', 'Colour', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('mileage', 'Mileage', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('long_desc', 'Description', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('purchase_price', 'Purchase Price', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('sale_price', 'Sale Price', 'trim|required');


        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $data['main_content'] = 'vehicle_display2';
            $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
        }

        else
        {           
            $this->load->model('manage_model');
            if($query = $this->manage_model->edit_stock_vehicle_record())
            {
                $data['main_content'] = 'vehicle_added';
                $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
            }
            else
            {

                $data['main_content'] = 'add_vehicle4';
                $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);      
            }
        }


    }
```

My model....

```
    function edit_stock_vehicle_record()
    {
        $this->load->helper('array');
        $this->load->helper('html');
        $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $config['upload_path'] = 'c:/wamp/www/honest/images';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '5000';
        $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
        $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);    

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            $data['main_content'] = 'imageupload';
            $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
            echo "FAILED";
        }
        else
        {

        $image_data = $this->upload->data();

        $vehicle_update_data = array(
            'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
            'make' => $this->input->post('make'),
            'model' => $this->input->post('model'),
            'fuel' => $this->input->post('fuel'),
            'enginesize' => $this->input->post('enginesize'),
            'trans' => $this->input->post('trans'),
            'reg_no' => $this->input->post('reg_no'),   
            'year' => $this->input->post('year'),
            'colour' => $this->input->post('colour'),
            'mileage' => $this->input->post('mileage'),
            'long_desc' => $this->input->post('long_desc'),
            'purchase_price' => $this->input->post('purchase_price'),           
            'sale_price' => $this->input->post('sale_price'),
            'image' => $image_data['file_name']

        );
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $update = $this->db->update('stock_vehicles', $vehicle_update_data, array('id' => $id));
        return $update;
        }
    }
```

I have also tried versions using....

```
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('stock_vehicles', $vehicle_update_data);
```

But this also fails, it seems as if the `$id` is not being recognized correctly.

If I remove the above and just use `$this->db->update('stock_vehicles', $vehicle_update_data);` it does indeed update *every* record in the db (doh!) Fortunately there was no 'real' data in there when I discovered this!

Not sure why it is not picking up the `$id` - all input gratefully received.

Cheers,

DP.

Comment: have u echo ur variable id is any id coming in it

Comment: can  u paste your url

Comment: try this $id= $this->uri->segment(3, 0);

Comment: first check any thing is coming in id or not;

Comment: url is http://localhost/honest/vehicle/edit/63 - and last segment is generated correctly. I am echoing this in the view with <?php echo $id; ?> and it displays correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a view with the form and this works and is pre-filled from the
>   db using $id = $this->uri->segment(3) to grab the correct record -
>   this all works.

Do NOT do this for the form update. Just include the id in a hidden form field. Much easier, safer, etc.

```
echo form_hidden( 'id', $id  );
```

Comment: PERFECT! - Thank loads.

Answer (score 0):

first you must load the url helper in your **Controller**:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

then you should try this code:

```
$id = $this->uri->segment(3);
$vehicle_update_data =array(
  'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
  'make' => $this->input->post('make'),
  'model' => $this->input->post('model'),
  'fuel' => $this->input->post('fuel'),
  'enginesize' => $this->input->post('enginesize'),
  'trans' => $this->input->post('trans'),
  'reg_no' => $this->input->post('reg_no'),   
  'year' => $this->input->post('year'),
  'colour' => $this->input->post('colour'),
  'mileage' => $this->input->post('mileage'),
  'long_desc' => $this->input->post('long_desc'),
  'purchase_price' => $this->input->post('purchase_price'),           
  'sale_price' => $this->input->post('sale_price'),
  'image' => $image_data['file_name']
);
$this->db->WHERE('id',$id)->update('your_table',$vehicle_update_data);
return true;
```

Comment: I have tried: $this->db->WHERE('id',$id)->update('your_table',$vehicle_update_data); but get same thing. I have also tried calling $id = $this->uri->segment(3); in the controller and passing the id to the model this way, but still no joy. I have also tried using a known record to test: $this->db->WHERE('id', 63)->update('your_table',$vehicle_update_data); and this works fine so I know it's not finding the $id - but I'll be damned if I can see why!

Comment: I also tried $id= $this->uri->segment(3, 0); with and without the additional zero - same result. :(

Comment: then try to pass id from html nd recive it from controller  function nd pass it to your model

Comment: in html like this  <a href="<?php echo $value['id'];?>" class="btn default btn-xs green">
          <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit </a>

Comment: add base_url() in before id

Comment: <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Edit Vehicle'); ?>  Can you show how to pass $id this way? Thanks.